slam_toolbox no /map_updates
I am trying to get slam_toolbox to run (humble on raspberry pi 5) but I am not getting map updates.
my tf_tree is: map -> odom -> base_link -> laser
odom_publisher node:
import rclpy
import sys
from rclpy.node import Node
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
sys.path.append('/robot')
from robotCom import init_robotCom
from odometer import check_odometer
import math

class OdomPublisher(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('odom_publisher')
        self.get_logger().info('Starting odom publisher')
        self.odom_publisher = self.create_publisher(Odometry, 'odom', 10)
        self.create_timer(0.1, self.publish_odom)
        self.start_time = self.get_clock().now()
        self.prev_right_wheel = 0
        self.prev_left_wheel = 0
        self.x = 0.0
        self.y = 0.0
        self.theta = 0.0

        init_robotCom()

    def publish_odom(self):
        current_time = self.get_clock().now()
        elapsed_duration = current_time - self.start_time
        dt = elapsed_duration.nanoseconds / 1e9
        odom_data = check_odometer() # -> distance covered in mm
        right_wheel = odom_data[0] / 1000 # -> meters
        left_wheel = odom_data[1] / 1000

        delta_right = right_wheel - self.prev_right_wheel
        delta_left = left_wheel - self.prev_left_wheel

        linear_velocity = (delta_right + delta_left) / 2.0
        angular_velocity = (delta_right - delta_left) / 0.3  # Distance between wheels

        # pose
        self.x += linear_velocity * math.cos(self.theta) * dt
        self.y += linear_velocity * math.sin(self.theta) * dt
        self.theta += angular_velocity * dt

        odom_msg = Odometry()
        odom_msg.header.stamp = current_time.to_msg()
        odom_msg.header.frame_id = 'odom'
        odom_msg.child_frame_id = 'base_link'
        odom_msg.pose.pose.position.x = self.x
        odom_msg.pose.pose.position.y = self.y
        odom_msg.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0
        odom_msg.pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0
        odom_msg.pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0
        odom_msg.pose.pose.orientation.z = math.sin(self.theta / 2.0)
        odom_msg.pose.pose.orientation.w = math.cos(self.theta / 2.0)
        odom_msg.pose.covariance = [0.1] * 36

         # twist
        odom_msg.twist.twist.linear.x = linear_velocity
        odom_msg.twist.twist.linear.y = 0.0
        odom_msg.twist.twist.linear.z = 0.0
        odom_msg.twist.twist.angular.x = 0.0
        odom_msg.twist.twist.angular.y = 0.0
        odom_msg.twist.twist.angular.z = angular_velocity
        
        # twist covariance
        odom_msg.twist.covariance = [0.1] * 36

        self.odom_publisher.publish(odom_msg)

        self.prev_right_wheel = right_wheel
        self.prev_left_wheel = left_wheel
        self.start_time = current_time

def main():
    rclpy.init()
    odom_publisher = OdomPublisher()
    try:
        rclpy.spin(odom_publisher)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    odom_publisher.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

this gives me following /odom output while driving:
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1716316099
    nanosec: 927677571
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: 0.5986000152292381
      y: -0.0025898238765142737
      z: 0.0
    orientation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: -0.007851670128521285
      w: 0.9999691751630112
  covariance:
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 0.03299999999999992
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 2.960594732333751e-15
  covariance:
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
  - 0.1
---

I run ros2 run slam_toolbox async_slam_toolbox_node --ros-args --params-file launch/params_slam_toolbox.yaml the parameter in the yaml are set as follows:
slam_toolbox:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: false
    update_rate: 1.0
    publish_period: 0.1
    resolution: 0.05
    max_laser_range: 8.0
    scan_topic: scan
    odom_frame: odom
    base_frame: base_link
    mode: mapping
    map_update_interval: 5.0
    transform_publish_period: 0.05
    linear_update: 0.1
    angular_update: 0.1
    scan_buffer_size: 10
    scan_buffer_maximum_scan_distance: 8.0
    lookup_transform_timeout_sec: 0.5
    minimum_time_interval: 0.5
    max_occupied_threshold: 0.65
    min_free_threshold: 0.196
    submap:
      number_of_cells: 3500

slam_toolbox gives me an initial map with this but when i drive around the map doesnt change and there are no updates on the /map_update topic..
any suggestions are welcome :)
